# How to enable color logs in nodejs program running in git-bash v.2.8.2 for windows?

Tags: node.js, git, bash

I had been using **Git for Windows 1.9.5** (installed from Git-1.9.5-preview20150319.exe). There was colored output from my nodejs program (gulp) in git-bash terminal. But when I uninstalled 1.9.5 and then installed **2.8.2** (Git-2.8.2-64-bit.exe) all output became monochrome except git-bash prompt line. How to utilize colored output in this newer 2.8.2 version? Or may be there is other suitable 2.x.x version (Visual Studio Code recommends this)

Comment: There is info about this in [this discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006#issuecomment-171129702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Windows environment variable](https://superuser.com/q/949560/6478) `FORCE_COLOR` and set it's value to `true` or `1`.

This solved my issue and all other team-members using Windows who had the same colors problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reason is in the new default type of terminal: MinTTY (the default terminal of MSYS2). The decision is to utilize a little bit modified (with regard to paths) version of the `Git Bash.vbs` file from version 1.9.5.

Comment: so, what is the answer? how do you enable colors? is it not possible?

Comment: It was working for me in 2.8.2. Then I switched to 2.10.2 and it left colors only in system prompt texts. In application text they are gone